# How change meta tags to make page more SEO firendly for both AJAX and none-AJAX requests in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, seo, asp.net-ajax

I have some pages that clients can request them with AJAX or none-AJAX requests and for SEO purpose i need to change meta tags for AJAX requests dynamically with Javascript (that seems is possible now) but i dont know what is best practice to do this?

My first solution is something like this:

views:

```
@{
var title = "title";
var keywords = "p1,p2";
var description = "des";
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { Layout = null; }//else i have a default layout for that!
}
```

```html
@section metas{
    <title>@title</title>
    <meta id="keywords" name="keywords" content="@keywords">
    <meta id="description" name="description" content="@description">
}

<div id="main">
    @{
        if (@Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            <script>
                document.title = "@title";
                document.getElementById('keywords').setAttribute("content", "@keywords");
                document.getElementById('description').setAttribute("content", "@description");
            </script>
        }
    }
  ...
```

And

_Layout:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    @RenderSection("metas", required: false)
...
  
      <div class="content">
        @RenderBody()
        ....
```

(Views will send as response data and will rewrite content of div with id="content" for AJAX requests).

It seems work fine but i am not sure it is a good solution.

any help appreciate!.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense. Search engines generally don't run the JavaScript on your site, so changing the meta-tags in JavaScript will not be detected by search engines. Related: [SEO Strategies for JavaScript-Heavy Single Page Applications or AJAX Sites](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2358775/seo-strategies-for-javascript-heavy-single-page-applications-or-ajax-sites)

Comment: @NightOwl888  thanks for answer. but what about this posts like https://www.merkleinc.com/blog/googlebot-crawling-javascript-your-site-ready#.V4SMO6Ivm0Y or some tests like  http://www.simoahava.com/seo/dynamically-added-meta-data-indexed-google-crawlers/#gref? i seen a lot of posts that believe SEs start to run javascripts.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected, thanks. But this only makes sense if the URL changes as well, as it would in a single page application. Good content is content you can *link directly to*, which is what search engines put in their SERPs (URLs). Also, search engines other than Google will probably completely ignore this.

Comment: Also note that [meta keywords is only used for detecting keyword spammers](https://chrisedwards.me/seo/keyword-meta-tag-google/), so you are better off not wasting time on it. Meta description is only used as the description of your page in the SERPs, [not as a ranking factor](http://relevance.com/blog/why-meta-descriptions-are-not-obsolete/). It is important to understand it can only be used for optimizing click-thru rates, not ranking.

Comment: @NightOwl888 You right about URL changes, and i actually use pushState HTML5 to solve this problem (at least for modern browsers). But thanks for useful link about meta tags.